# Populate a ListView with ViewCells at runtime in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I'm trying to fill a ListView with custom ViewCell objects at runtime and for some reason the Listview is populating with the type string names of the ViewCell objects instead of "inflating" with the actual ViewCell.

**Q: What do I need to do to get these ViewCells to "inflate" instead of just displaying their "ToString()" output?**

[image: Emulator output... worth a 1000 words?]

***Here is the very simple MainPage.xaml file:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ViewCellExperiment.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="mainListView"></ListView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

***And here is the very simple MainPage.xaml.cs file:***

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ViewCellExperiment
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var ListSource = new List<ViewCell>() { new CustomCell(), new CustomCell(), new CustomCell() };
            mainListView.ItemsSource = ListSource;
        }
    }
}
```

***And finally, here is the CustomCell.cs file:***

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ViewCellExperiment
{
    public class CustomCell : ViewCell
    {
        public CustomCell()
        {
            StackLayout cellWrapper = new StackLayout();
            StackLayout horizontalWrapper = new StackLayout();
            Label explanatoryText = new Label() { Text = "Explanatory text Label" };
            Button leftButton = new Button();
            Button centerButton = new Button();
            Button rightButton = new Button();

            horizontalWrapper.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
            cellWrapper.Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical;
            leftButton.Text = "Record";
            centerButton.Text = "Play";
            rightButton.Text = "Upload";

            horizontalWrapper.Children.Add(leftButton);
            horizontalWrapper.Children.Add(centerButton);
            horizontalWrapper.Children.Add(rightButton);
            cellWrapper.Children.Add(explanatoryText);
            cellWrapper.Children.Add(horizontalWrapper);

            View = cellWrapper;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your custom cell should be set as the DataTemplate for the ListView, not the ItemsSource.  ListView is a **templated** control - you define a template, and it applies that template to each item of the ItemsSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your custom cell should be set as the `DataTemplate` for the `ListView`, not the `ItemsSource`. `ListView` is a **templated** control - you define a template, and it applies that template to each item of the `ItemsSource`

[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance#custom-cells)